# Why 'click' event not triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to alert which button has been selected in an array of radio buttons.

But, why 'click' event not triggering?

```js
$('.selectedOption').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
  alert($('input[name=credit-card]:checked').val());
});
```

```css
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.visa {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);
}

.mastercard {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);
}

.cc-selector input:active+.drinkcard-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector input:checked+.drinkcard-cc {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}


/* Extras */

a:visited {
  color: #888
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
  <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc visa selectedOption" for="visa"></label>

  <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard selectedOption" for="mastercard"></label>
</form>
<small><a href="https://github.com/rcotrina94/icons">
    &copy; Icons by @rcotrina94 on Github</a></small>
```

Please see my code on jsfiddle

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/481anz1y/39/)

Comment: For starters you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: thanks for the tips. I added jQuery to fiddle. But as you can see, I don't get proper alert. It looks like i need to click a radio button twice before it start to know which button I was clicking.

Comment: you binded the click event to the label instead of input, so click the image(which is one lable), you will see the alert, but click the input(radio button), nothing happened. or you can hidde the input, then highlight the label if being selected.

Comment: Looks like there's a fraction of a second delay between when you click the label and when the radio button is checked. Easily remedied. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/o41baox0/

Comment: @Sphinx can you help me with the code for what you meant?

Comment: `$('input[name=credit-card]').on('change',function() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```
$( "input[type=radio]" ).on("click",
function () {

    alert($(this).val());
    alert($('input[name=credit-card]:checked').val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You binded the click event to the label instead of input, so click the image(which is one lable), you will see the alert, but click the input(radio button), nothing happened.

**My solution:**

You can hidde the input, then highlight the label if being selected.

1. use `<span>` to wrap each pair of input and label, then hide the input.
2. uses css selector like `input:checked + label` to render specific effects for selected card.

```js
$('input').change(function(e){
  console.log($('input[name=credit-card]:checked').val())
});
```

```css
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.visa {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);
}

.mastercard {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);
}

.cc-selector input:active+.drinkcard-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector input:checked+.drinkcard-cc {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}


/* Extras */

a:visited {
  color: #888
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

input:checked + label {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>hide inputs(radio buttons)</h3>
<form>
  <p>Now, with CSS3: </p>
  <span>
  <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" style="display:none"/>
  <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
  </span>
  <span class="selectedOption">
  <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" style="display:none" />
  <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard"></label>
  </span>
</form>
<small><a href="https://github.com/rcotrina94/icons">
    &copy; Icons by @rcotrina94 on Github</a></small>
```

Comment: @cb24 updated the answer, the border will be displayed when being selected.

Comment: quick question, when I add `border: 1px solid red;` to the `hover` class why my lable pictures move when mouse over?

Comment: @cb24, because border takes space. probably you prefer to using outline. check [css outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline),

Comment: As [css outline/border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) said, Borders and outlines are very similar. However, outlines differ from borders in the following ways:

    Outlines never take up space, as they are drawn outside of an element's content.
    According to the spec, outlines don't have to be rectangular, although they usually are.

Comment: ahh...yes the outline works. Thanks. Is there a way to make the outline or border exactly around the size of the image? As of right now, I see that the outline/or border is a little bigger than the actual image in the label.

Comment: check [css outline offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset), like `outline-offset:-3px`

Comment: I have a small problem. I am trying to determine which input was selected so that I can render a custom `div`. I am using the `.click` even like this `$('input[name=credit-card]').click(function () {...});` and it is rendering the custom div nicely. However, if after I move/proceed to another page and if I try to `go back` to the page again....then I don't see my event is firing. Question: how can I make the event fires so that I know exactly which input was selected when I use the `back button` to revisit that page that has all those inputs?

Comment: Not sure the root cause, but you can try `$('input[name=credit-card]').on('click',function(){})`, if still not working, please post one new question then put your current codes, then we can help you from there.

Comment: The input was selected but if i refresh the page...then the label corresponding to that input is not appear to be selected...but on the server side it still show that that input is selected. how can I make the label maintains its selected state even if there is a page refresh?